# php get both values from same key in array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to keep both values with the same key, but rename the other one.

I tried `array_merge()` but it only keeps the last value.

Here is what the array looks like

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [process] => A
            [start] => 0
        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [process] => A
            [end] => 1
        )

[2] => Array
        (
            [process] => A
            [start] => 9
        )

[3] => Array
        (
            [process] => A
            [end] => 14
        )
```

I want to keep only the first value of the key `end` but, keep both values of `start`. To make it like:

```
Array
            (
                [process] => A
                [start] => 0
                [start2] => 9
                [end] => 1
            )
```

Comment: it's not possible to keep 2 value with a single name

Comment: You will have to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it in PHP.  It's relatively simple, but there are a lot of checks that I had to manually add to the code to make it behave as you wanted.

```
<?php

$array = Array(Array
        (
            "process" => "A",
            "start" => 0
        ),Array
        (
            "process" => "A",
            "end" => 1
        ),Array
        (
            "process" => "A",
            "start" => 9
        ),Array
        (
            "process" => "A",
            "end" => 14
        ));

$returnValue = Array();
$returnValue["process"] = $array[0]["process"]; 
$flagFirstEnd = false;
$startI = 1;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (!$flagFirstEnd && isset($value["end"])) {
        $flagFirstEnd = true;
        $returnValue["end"] = $value["end"];
    }
    if (isset($value["start"])) {
        if ($startI == 1) {
            $returnValue["start"] = $value["start"];
        } else {
            $returnValue["start" . $startI] = $value["start"];
        }
        $startI++;
    }
}
print_r($returnValue);
?>
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives me four same arrays of process A

Comment: Are you referencing $returnValue?  If you want to modify the array object, simply reassign $array to $returnValue.

Answer (score 0):

Mabye the function `array_merge_recursive` will help you.

Its not the result that you expected but get a result like

```
Array
    (
        [process] => A
        [start] => Array (
            0,
            9
        )
        [end] => 1
    )
```

Look at [the documenation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) for more information.